# change font awesome icon rotate and scale in on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I have some static font awesome icons and I would like them each to change with some nice affect when a user hovers over them i.e. rotate a small bit and also pop out. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

They currently look like this:

[image]

My current icons:

```
 <div class="it-icons">
                  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/craig-whelan-515704196/">
                    <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
                  </a>
                  <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/craig1990">
                    <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                  </a>
                  <a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/12231949/darego101">
                    <i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
.it-icons a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
  background-color: #4582EC;
  color: #fff !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: For CSS3 you'll want to use [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) property (for scaling and rotating) and [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo class.

Comment: @adrift thanks a lot for the reply. Would you care to give me some code? I have not got a lot of front-end dev experience

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/5prsmvg3/) should get you started, but you should read the MDN links I referenced above as well for more flexibility.

Comment: Cheers exactly what I needed, thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.it-icons a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
  background-color: #4582EC;
  color: #fff !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all ease .3s;
}
.it-icons a:hover{
  transform: scale(1.15) rotate(25deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="it-icons">
              <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/craig-whelan-515704196/">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
              </a>
              <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/craig1990">
                <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
              </a>
              <a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/12231949/darego101">
                <i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing something like this, it's simple and it's not too flashy. In my opinion there shouldn't be any complicated animations on the site or if there are they should be kept to the minimum. Hope this helps you.

```
     .it-icons a {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 3.5rem;
        width: 3.5rem;
        background-color: #4582EC;
        color: #fff !important;
        border-radius: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        line-height: 3.5rem;
        margin-right: 1rem;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: 1s;
    }

    .it-icons a:hover {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        background-color: rgb(7, 63, 161);
    }
```